# error when trying to compile with MinGW: cannot execute cc1plus

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I did a clean install of MinGW on Windows 7 32bit with the GUI Installer, and installed

- ming32-base-bin
- mingw32-gcc-g++-bin
- msys-base-bin

When trying to compile a simple "Hello World.cpp" from the cmd.exe i get the error:

> C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop>g++ "Hello World.cpp" -o"Hello World.exe" -m32
> g++: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': CreateProcess: No such file or directory.
> compilation terminated.

The weird thing is that by grabbing the file from the desktop and putting it over g++.exe (so that i open the file with the application) in the MinGW directory, i don't get any error.

A temporary fix i found was to have a new environmet variable pointing in the folder where cc1plus is (C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0). The program runs but doesn't include the libraries from C:/MinGw/lib and C:/MinGw/Include, i have to include those manually, which shouldn't occur (i guess).
I don't want to do this crude fix since i know i'll encounter some other problems with time.

Comment: CreateProcess is not glibc function. This is Windows API (exists in windows.h and Kernel32.dll). So g++ ** is invalid. Please use Win32 C compiler or Replace CreateProcess as exec() func.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your environment variables. What does your `%PATH%` look like?

Comment: @SamuelD.Muprhy i'm sorry but i don't really get what you're saying. do i have to run the command from a different terminal? run a different compiler? sorry but i'm quite new to this.

Comment: @Botje Path: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\MinGW\bin;"

Comment: And where on your system is cc1plus.exe? It looks like that needs to be on your PATH as well.

Comment: _"A temporary fix i found was to have a new environmet variable pointing in the folder where cc1plus is (C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0)...  I don't want to do this crude fix since i know i'll encounter some other problems with time"._ The official wiki page doesn't say i have to do this, so i i'm guessing something's wrong and i want to know what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution with some luck.

It is as simple as adding *.exe* to *g++*

```
> g++.exe *input file* -o*output.exe*
```

Don't Know if it's a bug or not, but this works for me.

Comment: Also I would really recommend avoiding spaces in paths and filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which MinGW you used exactly, but it's better to use MinGW-w64.
There is a standalone build you can get from http://winlibs.com/ that doesn't require installation. The site also gives some instructions on how to use it.

Comment: why is it better to use MinGW-w64?

Comment: @L_or_Enzo it's more up to date (supports API of more recent Windows versions), and supports both 32 and 64 bit Windows.